# chisel asynch fifo / multiple clocks.

Tags: fifo, chisel

Does Chisel support multiple clocks in a design, yet? If I wanted to implement an asynchronous fifo how would one going about doing that in Chisel?

Comment: Yes, but I dont know much about the details myself. I'd read rocket-chip's code (https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip/blob/master/src/main/scala/util/AsyncQueue.scala) for a start.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Chisel support multiple clocks in a design. If you want to use an asynchronous fifo you can import module ChiselUtil, it contain an asynchronous fifo :
https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel/blob/master/src/main/scala/ChiselUtil.scala#L599

To change clock domain for a register, use the argument clock of Reg() :

```
val s1 = Reg(init = UInt(0), clock = clockB)
```

See more information in [tutorial](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/2.2.0/chisel-tutorial.pdf) chapter 16.

Comment: FYI, that's Chisel2, Chisel3 is about to land and I believe they handle it differently. https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3

Comment: But Chisel3 is not yet released. I hope it will released soon.